# Understand the flow of touch event in HTML5 , JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

In my project when we are touching one button another button is getting selected. I can not share the code here. But I am trying to understand the **flow of the touch event.**
My understanding is :

1. We click a button
2. Browser detects the event and let the HTML5 know.
3. HTML5 raises that as an event (like click)
4. HTML5 passes that to the JavaScript's event handlers.

So may be the  page.x and page.y co-ordinates detected  by the browser are wrong. 
**Kindly let me know if my understanding is wrong of the flow of touch event.**

Answer (score 0):

Check whether are you using same class for the buttons.

This may also due to event may get bubbled up this can be prevented by using event.stopPropagation().

Check this link https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/.

This is what i can suggest, if not please post a detail explanation.

Comment: I just want to know the flow of touch event